# Error launch activity due to google play services?

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services

I developed a project in android studio, but after a moment it does not execute the application, it opens and closes immediately.

I had a problem with the google play services library, can not access zzbfm play services maps
I have reviewed the gradle, the manifest but I can not find the error.

new :I have noticed that the application is running, I must press android studio 
stop.

This is my gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
//buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cspm.ventas6.cspm"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
 repositories {
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
   google()
 }
  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:location-tracker-background:v1.2'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
```

Comment: Post your error logs in your questions

Comment: What error are you getting? check your logcat

Comment: Please specify your question, post some error logs. And include more informations.

Comment: I have placed a try but it does not capture the error, the project has a tracking in backgroud to get the position of the device, sqlite, json parser, create file and send data to the server.

Comment: Click on Build->Clean Project and that will perform a gradle clean

Comment: I already do it and it does not solve